# Copy one table into another fails - "Column names in each table must be unique"

Tags: sql-server

When I try this:

```
SELECT * 
-- INTO DB2.dbo.CustomerOrderLines
FROM DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines 
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders ON DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Order_Display_Ref = DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines.Order_Display_Ref
WHERE DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Delivered_Date BETWEEN '2009-09-23' and '2009-09-24'
```

it show the rows correctly.

When I try to copy the contents from one table in DB1 into the same table in DB2 (and create it if it does not exist):

```
SELECT * 
INTO DB2.dbo.CustomerOrderLines
FROM DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines 
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders ON DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Order_Display_Ref = DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines.Order_Display_Ref
WHERE DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Delivered_Date BETWEEN '2009-09-23' and '2009-09-24'
```

it fails with

Msg 2705, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Order_Display_Ref' in table 'CustomerOrderLines' is specified more than once.

SELECT * INTO and INSERT INTO SELECT * work fine when copying other tables from one database into another, but they do not use JOINS.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to add the content of the DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines to DB2.dbo.CustomerOrderLines?

Then, tell SQL Server in your SELECT that you want only the content of this table.

```
SELECT DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines.* 
INTO DB2.dbo.CustomerOrderLines
FROM DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines 
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders ON DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Order_Display_Ref = DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines.Order_Display_Ref
WHERE DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Delivered_Date BETWEEN '2009-09-23' and '2009-09-24'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are joining two tables together which both have this Order_Display_Ref column in it. It looks like you only want the data from CustomerOrderLines so I would do :

```
SELECT DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines.* 
INTO DB2.dbo.CustomerOrderLines
FROM DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines 
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders ON DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Order_Display_Ref = DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines.Order_Display_Ref
WHERE DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Delivered_Date BETWEEN '2009-09-23' and '2009-09-24'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `CustomerOrderLines` and `CustomerOrders` have one or more columns where the name is the same, e.g. `CustomerOrderLines.Id` and `CustomerOrders.Id` would cause this kind of clash as your query would attempt to create two columns both called Id.

note : at least one of your problems is coming from the column `Order_Display_Ref`, which appears in both these tables.  There may be more.

Answer (score 1):

Both tables on DB1 have the `Order_Display_Ref`column, so it's trying to insert it twice. Simply supply a column list rather than * and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are joining DB1 table to itself and selecting all resulting columns. This will mean all column names are duplicated.

You need to specify the source you are inserting from:

```
SELECT DB1a.* 
INTO DB2.dbo.CustomerOrderLines
FROM DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines DB1a 
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders DB1b
  ON DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Order_Display_Ref = DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines.Order_Display_Ref
WHERE DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Delivered_Date BETWEEN '2009-09-23' and '2009-09-24'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply rename the column(s) having the same name.

```
SELECT

TableA.Column1,
TableA.Column1,
TableA.Column2,
TableA.Order_Display_Ref,
TableB.Order_Display_Ref as TableBOrder_Display_Ref,
TableB.ColumnN

INTO DB2.dbo.CustomerOrderLines
FROM DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines 
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders 
ON DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Order_Display_Ref = DB1.dbo.CustomerOrderLines.Order_Display_Ref
WHERE DB1.dbo.CustomerOrders.Delivered_Date BETWEEN '2009-09-23' and '2009-09-24'
```